# Release schedules

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it appropriate to ask a question about the release schedule of some Linux distributions?  Generally, that information is easy to find but in my case, not so much.  I am looking for CentOS/Scientific Linux 7 information.  So far, my Google fu has proved weak.

Comment: use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) for such

Comment: Even if you would ask Karanbir Singh he would give you the same answer as xenoterracide. The same is possibly true for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Release schedules have been known to change over time, I would consider this a localized problem, also known as "ask the developers". So no, please do not ask this.

Also CentOS/Scientific Linux are probably based on however long it takes them after Red Hat ships RHEL 7. It'll be done when it's done.